# How to wait for the previous job to complete in a for loop

Tags: tcl

Have to submit multiple jobs one at a time. should wait for my first job to complete before submitting the 2nd job.

tried with catch but didn't work.

with this code, the job doesn't wait for the first job to complete. The code prefectly works if I submit a single job without iteration.
for resource constraint, should wait for the previous job completion.

```
for {set count 0} {$count < $parellel_count} {incr count} {
set File "${runDir}/input.$count"
source ${File}
}
```

Comment: What signifies that a job has completed? Is there some file that will be written on completion?

Comment: As Donal writes, this is about what happens in the script file identified by `${File}`, you will need to show its content. The snippet you show is otherwise blocking.

Comment: @DonalFellows I am submitting a tool specific job and the tool would generate a report file after successful completion of each job. A file named "*.report" would be genrated after successful completion of each job.

Comment: @mrcalvin The script $File is a tool specific tcl script. As I mentioned, the script would generate a report file after successful completion of the job.

Comment: What's a "job"?

Comment: @Andreas I should have said after completetion of the script $File.